# Convert wrapped lines to single lines

Tags: notepad++, text-processing

I have a large file with wrapped lines:

```
 0              
  0.000    1.1    2.2   3.3  4.4    5.5    6.6    7.7  
  8.8   9.9    10.10    11.11

 5              
0.000    1.1    2.2   3.3  4.4    5.5    6.6    7.7  
  8.8   9.9    10.10    11.11
```

I would like to convert each record in a single line, like this:

```
0                0.000    1.1    2.2   3.3  4.4    5.5    6.6    7.7    8.8   9.9    10.10    11.11 

5                0.000    1.1    2.2   3.3  4.4    5.5    6.6    7.7    8.8   9.9    10.10    11.11
```

Each 3 lines downforward in the file

Someone can help me?

Comment: Hello, is the spacing correct? It looks weird. If not, please paste it correctly with code formatting.

Comment: What have you tried and what research have you done?

Answer (score 0):

You can do a find for (with *Serach Mode*: *Regular expression* selected):

```
(.*)\r\n(.*)\r\n(.*\r\n)(.*\r\n)
```

And replace with:

```
\1\2\3\4
```

Press *Replace All*.

This will cut out the 1st and 2nd line breaks (leaving the 3 lines together) and then leave in place the next two (the empty line and the start of a new record.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this option works excellent!!

Comment: @Julio, If my answer answered your question, please accept it as the answer by ticking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This removes all linebreak when not followed by another linebreak.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `\R(?!\R)`
- Replace with: `LEAVE EMPTY
- **TICK** *Wrap around*
- **SELECT** *Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
\R          # any kind of linebreak
(?!\R)      # negative lookahead, make sure we haven't a linebreak after
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]